# how to get the coordinate？ (tensorflow label model object detection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

HI all could someone please help me?

I want to know the rectangle coordinate

(left up and right dow)
I reference this https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_webcam.py

is it need to use the 'boxes'? and how let tensorflow know which is the rectangle coordinate?

is the following right? and is it need to be int?
x_left = 1280*(np.squeeze(boxes[0,0,1]))

y_left = 640 *(np.squeeze(boxes[0,0,0]))

x_right = 1280*(np.squeeze(boxes[0,0,3]))

y_right = 640 *(np.squeeze(boxes[0,0,2]))
------------------------------------------------------------------is it need to be int?

x_left = int(round(x_left))

y_left = int(round(y_left))

x_right= int(round(x_right))

y_right= #int(round(y_right))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYmWy.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngKXC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs2Ga.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx3fD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDMF9.png)

Comment: I reached at your question. Can you please tell me from where we get coordinates of bounding boxes. Tensorflow. As you shared a list of coordinates. I need it for cropping BB. Can you please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boxes` is an array of normalized coordinates. The length of the `boxes` array is equal to the number of detection. For index `i`,

```
boxes[i]=[x_left, y_left, x_right, y_right],
```

where `x_left`, `y_left`, `x_right`, `y_right` are in the interval [0,1].

If the image fed to the model was of height `H` and width `W`, the coordinates of the box are

```
x_left = int(W*x_left)
y_left = int(H*y_left)
x_right = int(W*x_right)
y_right = int(H*y_right).
```